# Azure run command for Fortinet virtual machine with serial console?

Tags: azure, console, invoke-command, runcommand, fortigate

I'm trying to execute with Azure a .conf file that has some command lines that are executable into the Fortinet's serial console in a virtual machine with FortiOS v6.4.3 (Linux based system).

I use AZ CLI to execute the script into the virtual machine. the command is the following:

```
az vm run-command invoke --subscription "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" --resource-group "myresourcegroup" --name "myfortinet" --command-id RunShellScript --scripts $scriptfgtvm
```

Where $scriptfgtvm contains this:

```
config system interface
edit port1
set allowaccess ping https ssh fgfm snmp
next
end
```

The problem is that we don't see the modifications desired, and thE feedback is "Not supported" but successfully Provisioned.

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "code": "ProvisioningState/succeeded",
      "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded",
      "level": "Info",
      "message": "Not supported.",
      "time": "2021-08-05T08:24:01+00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

When we connect to the vm remotely through SSH we get into the serial console, not into the shell console, the same with Azure Bastion

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like serial console support is available yet for Azure CLI ([source](https://github.com/Microsoft/azserialconsole/issues/47)).